# Nginx not making proxy_pass when getting files (other than index.html) from Apache's Document Root

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy, documentroot

I think I'm chasing my own tail here and I've decided to ask all you gurus.

I have two machines, one has a reverse proxy Nginx and the other an Apache running several virtual hosts.

The nginx correctly does the proxy_pass and I'm able to view the index.html, but not any other file than that.

I attach the conf file for the nginx host (nbte.com.br, (192.168.4.30)) and the apache virtual host (SIPREPWWPRESS03.simosa.inet)

**NGINX - 083-nbte.conf**

```
server {

listen       80;
server_name  nbte.com.br www.nbte.com.br;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/nbte.access.log;
error_log   /var/log/nginx/nbte.error.log error;

error_page   404 403           /handle404.html;
#error_page   502 503 504  /handle503.html;
error_page   500 502 503 504   /handle500.html;

location = /handle404.html {
     root html/errores-prxy;
}

location = /handle503.html {
     root html/errores-prxy;
}

location = /handle500.html {
     root html/errores-prxy;
}

location = / {
    proxy_pass http://SIPREPWWPRESS03.simosa.inet/;
}
```

SIPREPWWPRESS03.simosa.inet resolves to 192.168.16.79

**APACHE - 021-nbte.conf**

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.16.79:80>

    ServerName    nbte.com.br
    ServerAlias   nbte.com.br www.nbte.com.br

    DocumentRoot "/apps/htmlsites/nbte"

    ErrorLog "logs/error_nbte.log"
    CustomLog "logs/nbte-access.log" combined

    <LocationMatch "/*">

    </LocationMatch>

    <Directory "/apps/htmlsites/nbte">
            Options +Indexes FollowSymLinks
            #AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>


    # ModSecurity exceptions
    <LocationMatch "/*">
            SecRuleRemoveById 990011
            SecRuleRemoveById 960017
            SecRuleRemoveById 960015
            SecRuleRemoveById 970013
    </LocationMatch>
```

I've almost no experience with NGINX, I'm very very new to it and specially it's reverse proxy functioning. Nevertheless, I think it's a NGINX issue, since looking at the error log file I find error lines each time a static file is requested:

```
2015/06/25 12:00:04 [error] 5075#0: *1393 open() "/etc/nginx/html/Informacoes-Financeiras-30-junho-2014-Norte-Brasil-Transmissora-Energia.pdf" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.14.1, server: nbte.com.br, request: "GET /Informacoes-Financeiras-30-junho-2014-Norte-Brasil-Transmissora-Energia.pdf HTTP/1.1", host: "nbte.com.br", referrer: "http://nbte.com.br/"


2015/06/25 12:00:04 [error] 5075#0: *1393 open() "/etc/nginx/html/Informacoes-Financeiras-30-junho-2014-Norte-Brasil-Transmissora-Energia.pdf" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.14.1, server: nbte.com.br, request: "GET /Informacoes-Financeiras-30-junho-2014-Norte-Brasil-Transmissora-Energia.pdf HTTP/1.1", host: "nbte.com.br", referrer: "http://nbte.com.br/"
```

The file **Informacoes-Financeiras-30-junho-2014-Norte-Brasil-Transmissora-Energia.pdf** is located inside Apache's document root /apps/htmlsites/nbte alog with index.html

Many thanks in advance. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
location = / {
proxy_pass http://SIPREPWWPRESS03.simosa.inet/;
}
```

Should be

```
location / {
proxy_pass http://SIPREPWWPRESS03.simosa.inet/;
}
```

As per http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#location

> location  = / {
>     # matches the query / only.
>     [ configuration A ]
>   }
>
> location  / {
>     # matches any query, since all queries begin with /, but regular
>     # expressions and any longer conventional blocks will be
>     # matched first.
>     [ configuration B ]
>
> Example requests:
>
> / -> configuration A
>   /index.html -> configuration B

Comment: Indeed this was the reason :-) I changed it and now it's serving all the statics from the Apache.
Thank you for your time and your solution!
Best regards!